# CollectionView Images Don't Load After Scroll

Tags: xamarin.forms, tizen

On Tizen.NET with Xamarin.Forms, scrolling through a CollectionView (or CarouselView) unloads off-screen images but sometimes fails to load them when they come into view again. This happens most often after scrolling across many items quickly. How can I force an image to load after a scroll?

[image: Five white columns, the first two containing a photograph of a grey kitten on a red sheet, the last three blank.]

View a video recording of the problem here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qs5hg.jpg

Here's the code I've written

```
    public partial class TestCollectionView : ContentPage
    {
        public TestCollectionView ()
        {
            var view = new CollectionView();
            view.ItemsLayout = new LinearItemsLayout(ItemsLayoutOrientation.Horizontal) { ItemSpacing = 50 };
            var items = new Uri[]
            {
                new Uri("https://placekitten.com/150/151?a"),
                new Uri("https://placekitten.com/150/150?b"),
                new Uri("https://placekitten.com/150/149?c"),
                new Uri("https://placekitten.com/150/152?d"),
                new Uri("https://placekitten.com/150/148?e"),
                new Uri("https://placekitten.com/149/153?f"),
                new Uri("https://placekitten.com/148/147?g"),
                new Uri("https://placekitten.com/153/153?h"),
                new Uri("https://placekitten.com/154/143?i"),
                new Uri("https://placekitten.com/144/157?j"),
                new Uri("https://placekitten.com/156/141?k"),
                new Uri("https://placekitten.com/154/154?l"),
                new Uri("https://placekitten.com/148/148?m"),
                new Uri("https://placekitten.com/148/154?n"),
                new Uri("https://placekitten.com/145/154?o"),
                new Uri("https://placekitten.com/154/154?p"),
                new Uri("https://placekitten.com/143/143?q"),
                new Uri("https://placekitten.com/147/147?s"),
            };
            view.ItemsSource = items;

            view.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
            {
                var img = new Image();
                img.HeightRequest = 350;
                img.WidthRequest = 350;
                img.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
                img.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, new Binding("."));
                return img;
            });
            Content = view;

            var index = 0;
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(500);
                    index++;
                    if (index >= items.Count())
                    {
                        index = 0;
                    }
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            view.ScrollTo(items[index]);
                        }
                        catch { }
                    });
                    if(index == 0)
                    {
                        await Task.Delay(5000);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: If there is an event handler for end of scroll or user lifting finger, then try `view.ForceLayout();`. Probably wrapped in Device.Begininvokeonmainthread, so it happens after XF has finished its update.

Comment: look into the built in image caching, or use FFImageLoading for caching

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve forcelayout didn't work, but thank you for the suggestion

Comment: @Jason FFImageLoading fixed it perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: Perhaps add Your Answer with a small code snippet, to help others in future?